# How to efficiently decode a image knowing only its path

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm creating my own gallery using ViewPager, which is 'connected' to ArrayList holding paths of images to display.

So far, I use:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

It's working, but the pictures are pretty big and I unnecessarily decode whole picture, because it's scaled down later to fit layout. It is slow and a crash with OutOfMemoryError happens sometimes, when I scroll fast.

So the question is:
How can I efficiently decode an image so it fits 100% with ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE knowing only its path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not decode it directy. use `inJustDecodeBounds = true` from `BitmapFactory.Options`, to load only width and height from the Bitmap. Then you can calcuate the `inSampleSize` to scale your `Bitmap`

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

decodeFile will return null and options will contains `width` and `height`. Then you calculate the `inSampleSize` and:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inSampleSize = myInsampleSize;
Bitmap output = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great. Although I have one question: how can I decode with specific size, like 50x50?

Comment: use a combination of `inSampleSize` and `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`